# Saving int values to Array when app closes

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an Iphone app that uses alot of int values that will increment on IBActions, I want to save the int values to an array when the app closes so that these values are stores and used when the app is reopened. I am not sure how to write int values into an array. Functionally, I am getting this to wort with text field but not integers i.e.

int count;

code used:

```
NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:fieldOne.text,fieldTwo.text,count, nil];
```

This gives an "Assignment makes integer from pointer without cast" message.

Is there anyway to write already stored int values into and array?
code I used is as follows:

I thinks its ok until the calling the data into the array. I have commented out some failed efforts

```
-(NSString *) saveFilePath{

    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savefile.plist"];
}


-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground: (UIApplication *) application{
    //NSNumber *num = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:count];
    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:fieldOne.text,fieldTwo.text,[NSNumber numberWithInt:count],nil];
    [values writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
    [values release];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    //NSNumber *num = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:count];
    NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath];

    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];
    if (fileExists) {
        NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
        fieldOne.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
        fieldTwo.text = [values objectAtIndex:1];
        //[NSNumber count intValue] = [values objectAtIndex:2];
        [values release]; 
    }


    UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector (applicationDidEnterBackground:)name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:myApp];


     [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use NSNumber so something like:

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:int];
```

which will give you an object containing your int. To read back from it, use `[num intValue]`

Comment: Thank you, trying to get my head round this one. I am saving the values to an array on applicationDidEnterBackground and writing the data on viewDidLoad, I am not sure where to create this NSNumber or how it fits into the array . Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can replace your previous line of `NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:fieldOne.text,fieldTwo.text,count, nil];` With `NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:fieldOne.text,fieldTwo.text,[NSNumber numberWithInt:count], nil];`

Comment: Thanks, when I am populating the details would I use: NSNumber numberWithInt:count = [values objectAtIndex:2];

Comment: To pass into the array you use numberWithInt: and to get out you use [*nsnumber instance* intValue] which will return an int. If you wanna post some more code ill take a look.

Comment: Thanks again, I have added the code to the description above.

Comment: I assume count is an instance variable so it would just be `count = [[values objectAtIndex:2]intValue];`

Comment: App now crashes :(, maybe need to look at this from a different angle, not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Well what is count and what does it do? what was the crash?

Comment: As soon as the app opens it crashes. int count; is declared in the .h file and is a simple counter to show how many times a button has been clicked, this int is used on another button press to change the text on a label giving a running total. I want to store this count to give a running total, if I remove count = [[values objectAtIndex:2]intValue]; the crash no longer happens.

Comment: what error do you get in the console? Its probably because its loading an old file without the nsnumber in it. add in `if ([values count]>2) {` around your `count = [object.....` line. Should fix it.

Comment: Some goods new from your good help, managed to get it kind of working, if I add more int values I get the following error in the console, NSRangeException index (3) beyond bounds (3). Almost there :)

Comment: Thats the same problem again, you are reading a file with 2 values in and asking for the third. Run the app with the saving function in before adding the reading funcitonality. If you are sorted then please mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: Excellent help, thank you. 2 questions = 1) Is it also possible to store floats in the same array, would it just be [NSNumber numberwithFloat:test] and test = [[values objectAtIndex:17] floatValue];  Also have you ever had issues loading the data in the wrong order. These int are used to change labels but the correct labels are no being changed, they seem to be allover the place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10179/discussion-between-martin-and-tj15)

Answer (score 0):

Create a NSNumber object with your count as its value and put the object into your array.  NSArrays need to be arrays of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Container classes work with Objects not fundamental types. You have to wrap fundamental types in NSNumber (numbers) , NSData etc.